# Want to know how to solve this high order differential equation system with boundary condition?

Tags: python, boundary-conditions

[image]

[image]

The numerical results may be like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [scipy.integrate.solve_bvp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_bvp.html)?

Comment: What have you tried already? Your question does not actually contain a question, or description of what you have already done and what software you have looked at.